# Estimate Annual Maintenance Cost

Tags: cost-estimation, maintenance

Suppose, I am trying to install a completely new manufacturing plant, so I have no previous data to help me. 
I want to calculate a rough estimate of my annual maintenance cost of machinery. Is there a way possible?

Note: We have purchased reused, refurbished machinery so there is no maintenance schedule book of any kind

Answer (score 2):

Machinery manufacturers provide a maintenance schedule, just like car manufacturers give you a service book.

Once you have that then you can estimate the time required for each service operation, whether it is an inspection, lubrication or strip/rebuild.

So: Hours_Machine_1 + Hours_Machine_2 + ... = Total hours / year

Once you have that you can then work out how many staff you will need and when you need them during the year.

Then, for 1 member of staff:

Hours_per_week * (52 weeks - holidays, sickness etc) = Total hours available per year

Dividing the first result by the second will tell you how many staff you need, and you can work out all the other costs. Don't forget the parts/ material that you have to purchase.

One important thing to remember about the cost of maintenance:

```
Pay now or Pay more later
```

delaying preventative maintenance tends to increase the cost of it, as badly maintained items cause needless damage to other parts.

Edit based on change to the original question:
So check out similar machinery suppliers websites and find service information. Or, create your own service schedule based on experience and knowledge. Perhaps you already own similar machines and can work from there.

The downside of purchasing second-hand, of course, is that you do not know how well, or how badly, the machine was maintained in its previous life. So a **thorough** service and inspection (checking lubrication, tolerances, especially safety items etc etc) is advised prior to putting the machine to work.

And "refurbished" can mean many things, just like second-hand car dealers: some good, some bad...

Comment: thanks @Solar Mike.... the point is, we have purchased used, refurbished machinery and there is no maintenance schedule associated with it. Is it still possible to estimate??

Comment: @MayankDhiman so check out similar machinery suppliers websites and find service information. Or, create your own service schedule based on experience and knowledge.